# MySQL PDOで複数テーブル（tableA,tableB) where (tableB.metaID=tableA.id)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

コードの通り、テーブル名`wp_posts`のカラム名`post_id`に一致するテーブル名`wp_postmeta`のカラム名`post_id`を一回のSQL文で取得したいです。下記の場合では取得できませんでした。

```
$str1 = 'post';
$str2 = 'publish';
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("

SELECT * FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = %s 
AND wp_posts.post_status = %s
AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.post_id
ORDER BY post_date DESC 
LIMIT 25
", $str1, $str2));
```

データベース中身はこうなっています。
wp_posts
post_id 1001 PRIMARY
post_title LION

post_id 1002 PRIMARY
post_title TIGER

wp_postmeta
meta_id 8501 PRIMARY
post_id 1001
key LEO
val RAION

meta_id 8502 PRIMARY
post_id 1001
key NEKO
val TANAKA

Comment: 文法はあっています。post_type, post_statusは中身の説明に出てきませんが、値はあってますか？

Comment: status, typeはすべてpublish, postで統一されていて、これに間違いはありません。文法があっているかも心配でしたので、少し安心しました。ありがとうございます

Comment: そのSQLだと、`wp_posts`と`wp_postmeta`が内部結合してるのでWordpressのカスタムフィールドを持たない記事は結果に含まれませんが期待通りですか？またカスタムフィールドが複数あると `wp_postmeta.post_id` は重複すると思いますがそれも期待通りですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず純粋にSQL文レベルで話として

> wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.post_id

と結合できるのであれば、`post_id`を得るために`wp_postmeta`テーブルを見る必要はなく`wp_posts`テーブルを見れば済むことでしょう。

次にWordPressについて、公式ドキュメントの[データベース概要 - テーブル： wp_posts](http://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81#.E3.83.86.E3.83.BC.E3.83.96.E3.83.AB.EF.BC.9A_wp_posts)を見ますと投稿IDのフィールドは`post_id`ではなく`ID`とのことですが、カラム名は本当に正しいですか？

また、インストール時にテーブル名の接頭辞は変更できるため、`$wpdb`を使って

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = %s AND post_status = %s
    ORDER BY post_date DESC 
    LIMIT 25
    ", $str1, $str2));
```

とするそうです。

Comment: `wp_postmeta`にサムネイル画像など情報が入っているため、必要になります。公式では`ID`ですが分かりやすいように`post_id`とStackOverflowでの表記です。接頭辞についての理解は得ています。`wp_`とわかりやすいように表記しました

Comment: @まめたろう 「カラム名post_idを一回のSQL文で取得したいです」という質問文に対して回答しました。質問を簡略化したなら回答も簡略化されて当然です。また説明なくカラム名を変更する行為は質問者以外に誰一人として理解することはできないため決してわかりやすい表記ではありません。

Comment: 誤解を招くような質問をして申し訳ございません。
SELECT文を2つ使うことにしました。

Answer (score 1):

試してないので間違ってたらすみません。
まず重複を排除するには `SELECT DISTINCT` を使います。

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_posts.post_date
  FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_posts on wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id 
 WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

もし `wp_posts` には存在するが、`wp_postmeta` には存在しない レコードを含めるには外部結合(LEFT JOIN)を使います。

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_posts.post_date
  FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_posts on wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id 
 WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```